# DataTables editor - how to disable validation on bulk select and edit modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable with inline and bulk select edit options. It works fine when editing using the inline mode. But on selecting multiple rows and editing through the modal, it validate unnecessarily.

I don't want to validate some fields in the bulk edit modal. Instead, it should work as it is for inline edits.

Is it possible to disable validations in the bulk edit modal?